# Flask change image with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, python, html, flask, web-applications

I'm working on Flask and I'm stuck in a strange situation.
I'm trying to change an image with javascript but flask gives me these errors:

... 12:05:34] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 -

... 12:05:38] "GET /img/immagine.jpg HTTP/1.1" 404 -

JS:

```
var btnAddImage = document.getElementById("btnAddImage");
btnAddImage.onclick = function() {
  var img = document.createElement("img");
  img.src = "/static/img/immagine.jpg.jpg";
  document.getElementById("asi").appendChild(img);
};
```

As you can see in the path it's specified as static but it's not read.

I'm using the simply render_template method:

```
from flask import Flask, render_template
app = Flask(__name__)


@app.route("/")
def hello():
    return render_template('index.html', nome=nome)
    enter code here
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error message clearly states that the image could not be found.

Your code does not match the error message. One time you have `.jgp` as file ending, one time `.jpg.jpg`.

Try to compare the image name and path with the one you write in your code.

If you cannot figure out how to fix this, please also give us an overview of your directory structure.

Comment: sorry it's an error in the vary test but it don't resolve the problem. 

the structure is project(static(img(svg1,svg2,img1,img2,img3)script.js,jquery,main.css)templates(page1,page2)app.py)

Comment: There is still no `immagine.jpg` in your project structure - either that is the problem or you  want to make it really suprising for those who want to help you :-)

Comment: Is your code public available e.g on GitHub? Then I could clone your project and have a look at my machine.

Comment: thanks for help I think that depends by pycharm or chrome because when i change the name of the javascript file it change but i don't know why now

Comment: EDIT: with firefox works this is how I point to JS file <script type="text/javascript" src="{{ url_for('static',filename='ilmioscript.js') }}"></script>.
If you prefer the project tell me