# Flask changing image with javascript

Tags: javascript, html, image, flask

I am trying to create a project using Flask. I've got a html file, and I'm trying to pass an image from a javascript file to the html. In the html code I've got this part:

```
<div id="qImg"></div>
```

And in the javascript part I have an image link at q.imgSrc (the image is saved in a folder named "static", as needed in flask). Then I write this part in the javascript code:

```
qImg.innerHTML = '<img src="' + "{{ url_for('static', filename=" + q.imgSrc + ")}}" + "/>"
```

Note that q.imgSrc is the link of the image, and it is surrounded by ' ', so for example if q.imgSrc = '1.png' the above line should give:

`qImg.innerHTML = '<img src="{{ url_for('static', filename='1.png')}}"/>'`

When I write this line in the html file itself without passing the image through js, it actually works and presents the image '1.png' like I wanted, but in this case (when I'm passing it through js) it doesn't work for me. I'm stuck on this issue for a long time, what am I doing wrong, and how do I fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, notice that there is a similar post to it:
[Flask change image with JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62832197/flask-change-image-with-javascript)

---

To load images with JavaScript to a website, rendered by flask, you don't need the form of {{ url_for ...

This is only required, for static elements in the webpage. So it means, if you have a simple webpage like the following one, where you have a normal img-container, it is required to use that notation:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <img src="{{ url_for('static', filename='1.png') }}">
</body>
</html>
```

But if you create for example an img in javascript, so after loading the webpage, you can simply do:

```js
let img = document.createElement("img");
img.src = "static/1.png";
document.body.appendChild(img);
```

and if the url is correct it loads it without problems.

Note that if you use javascipt you need to add it in your html like this:

```html
<script src="{{ url_for('static', filename='main.js') }}"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

The html is being rendered by Flask's templating engine on the server (the weird brackets and url_for function is a Flask function, I guess).

On the other hand, the JavaScript is running on the client's browser - i.e. not on the server and hence with no access to Flask.

I mean, this is why I think you're better off just learning how to actually create websites using the fundamental building blocks, first - HTML, JS and CSS. For dynamic content, why not use Php? It is an easy language for beginners, is significantly faster than Python and has great support. To me, Python just has this mainstream cult-like following...most likely you learnt Python because some other inexperienced programmer said it was cool. Realistically, you are going to run into less issues with a more supported language specifically designed for the backend - as opposed to having to hack together a load of completely different Python libraries, all of which have different dependencies to try and create some sort of monstrousity.

Like, you are adding this extra complexity with Python/Flask...but what benefit does it actually give you? You'd be better off learning how things actually work at a more fundamental level...rather than trying to adapt a hammer to become a spanner...

Comment: This is a school project and these are the instructions, I need to use flask and I'm trying to understand how to have a dynamic picture in my html code through js.